# Using arrays in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm using file_get_contents() to search an off site text file, which returns an array as follows:

```
$foo_data = file_get_contents('http://foo/data_csv.php?code='.$row->code);
$foo_code = explode(",",$foo_data);
$foo_id = $foo_code[9];
```

If I place the above lines before the MySQL Select statement then the $foo_data variable is empty as it hasnt been initialised yet.

How do I reference this variable in the MySQL statement eg:

```
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, COUNT(distinct $foo_id) AS Ref
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, COUNT(distinct {$foo_id}) AS Ref
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, COUNT(distinct '{$foo_id}') AS Ref
```

Anyone know if it's possable to reference a table row from the array obtained in the above file_get_contents() ?

Complete code as follows:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/class2.php';
Global $currentUser;
$user_name = $currentUser['user_loginname'];
$user_call = strtoupper($user_name);
$user_region = $currentUser['user_region'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?
include("db_uploadlog.php");
if (!file_exists("db_uploadlog.php")) {
echo "Error - Config file is missing!";
}
else
{
$db_2 = mysql_connect($database_host, $database_username, $database_password);
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Cannot select database");

$foo_data = file_get_contents('http://foo.com/data_csv.php?code='.$row->code);
$foo_code = explode("|",$foo_data);
$foo_id - $foo_code[9]

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `column1`, `column1_id`, `code`, `column1_region`, '{$foo_id}' AS score FROM $table GROUP BY `column1` ORDER BY score DESC", $db_2);
$rowpos = mysql_num_rows($result);
$mnum = 1;
$mnum2 = 1;

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
?>

<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="2%"><b>Pos</b></td>
<td><b>Code</b></td>
<td width="10%"><b>Score</b></td>
</tr>
<?
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $mnum2; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row->column1; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row->score; ?></td>
</tr>
<?
$mnum2 = $mnum2 + 1;
$mnum = $mnum + 1;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($db_2);
?>
</table>
</div>
<?
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want your query to do?

Comment: It is unclear what you ask.

Comment: My query is using the value in $row->code as the id to be used in file_get_contents e.g. file_get_contents('http://foo/data_csv.php?code=ABC'); will search the csv file for a field value of "ABC" and return that record as an array. I can manually enter a value like "ABC" and that works, but when I try to use the contents of $row->code then this fails as there doesnt seem to be any $row->code instanciated yet so the order in which I have things set in my script may be at fault here, or maybe I have to use file_get_contents() in the MySQL select statement.

Comment: Hopefully, this error was eventually corrected: $foo_id - $foo_code[9], should be '=' not '-'. It could cause quite a lot of confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Edited according to comment:

Then your problem is that `file_get_contents` don't recover data, you have to activate the property [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php), set this property to 1 on your php.ini and your code should work

But i recommend you to use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` you will have more control and `curl` was designed for this isn't it?

Comment: Just tried backsticks and that killed the query, no results at all. Removing the backsticks returned results but with empty $foo_id.

Comment: Then you don't have any value in $foo_id

Comment: Agreed, My question is how do I get the contents of $row->code loaded into $foo_data ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have confirmed that file_get_contents does work if I manually provide a known value in place of $row->code. My problem is that I cant get the value of $row->code to populate the file_get_contents command. So maybe my syntax for: file_get_contents('http://foo/data_csv.php?code='.$row->code); is incorrect and it's not getting the field value? I'll read up on CURL and see if this is any better. Thanks

Comment: Update your question with complete code, including when you recover `$row`

Answer (score 0):

"If I place the above lines before the MySQL Select statement then the $foo_data variable is empty as it hasnt been initialised yet. "
This is probably because you reference the results from the MySQL select in your file_get_contents.

Other than that it should work, you are basically making a string in PHP and sending it to the MySQL server for parsing. So to MySQL it wont matter if you type it in by hand or if you use some pregenerated value.

Though, you need to trust the source if you are assembling the string from external sources, otherwise you should use PDO with bindParam.

**edit**
I see my initial thought was correct,

```
$foo_data = file_get_contents('http://foo.com/data_csv.php?code='.$row->code);
```

Here $row->code hasn't been initialized yet so file_get_contents goes to "http://foo.com/data_csv.php?code=" (if it goes anywhere at all).

You need to have another select above $foo_data which sets $row->code.

PHP normally shows an error message, but you probably are running on production mode. If you are testing you can put this in the top of your document

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

Which should help you debug your script a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, the source is trustworthy, but I do take your point. I will convert this script to PDO if I can get this MyQSL version working first.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply, I've been away for the past week. I have updated my question including my full code as requested.

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't have a value in $row->code when you access it in file_get_contents.